# Adding natively compiled C++ DLL to CLR C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, clr

I have a C++ DLL compiled natively and I'd like to write a CLR wrapper for it. After building the DLL and placing it in the CLR project directory I added the header file to correspond to it.

When I build I get linker errors about the functions in the DLL not existing.

I've already tried adding the DLL to the 'executable directory'.

How do I link up the external DLL to the CLR C++ project?

Comment: Why is a C++ CLR project any different than any other C++ project? Can't you just reference the include directory, and the path to your corresponding exp file or lib, and compile?

Comment: A native DLL is not like a .NET assembly, you don't add a reference and you don't link it directly.  You must link its import library (.lib) instead.  Linker + Input + Additional Dependencies setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a linker error, you probably forgot to include the .exp or .lib file associated with your DLL in your Additional Dependencies. Usually MSVC will generate a .exp and/or .lib file to help you link to your DLL.

Comment: How are you building the DLL?

Comment: It was my bad, I wasn't using dllexport in the code anywhere so visual studio was not generating any output files.. Haven't done C++ DLL builds in a while, had forgotten about that.